# Calculate row-wisely cumulative product inside same year-month with Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a panel dataframe as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2021)
dates = pd.date_range('20130226', periods=90)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(90, 3)), index=dates, columns=list('ABC'))
df
```

Out:

```
                   A         B         C
2013-02-26  0.211957  0.466739 -0.722106
2013-02-27 -0.374654  0.994487 -0.743675
2013-02-28 -0.642014  0.505851  0.324321
2013-03-01  0.568620 -0.806211 -0.882857
2013-03-02  0.924792  0.233115 -0.826740
             ...       ...       ...
2013-05-22 -0.879038  0.525579 -0.712993
2013-05-23  0.092874  0.533207  0.138656
2013-05-24 -0.572822 -0.721276 -0.918456
2013-05-25  0.305165  0.043782  0.263586
2013-05-26  0.358002 -0.522929 -0.745974
```

I need to add 1 to columns `A` and `B` and then apply cumulative product row-wisely inside **each year-month**.

For example, the new values for `A` in 2013-02-28 will be `1.211957 * 0.625346 * 0.357986`.

To add a constant `1` for column `A` and `B`, I use:

```
df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']] + 1
```

Out:

```
                   A         B
2013-02-26  1.211957  1.466739
2013-02-27  0.625346  1.994487
2013-02-28  0.357986  1.505851
2013-03-01  1.568620  0.193789
2013-03-02  1.924792  1.233115
             ...       ...
2013-05-22  0.120962  1.525579
2013-05-23  1.092874  1.533207
2013-05-24  0.427178  0.278724
2013-05-25  1.305165  1.043782
2013-05-26  1.358002  0.477071
```

How could I acheive that in Pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below seems works out, thanks for sharing other possible solutions:

```
df[['A', 'B']].resample('M').transform(lambda x: x.cumprod())
```

Out:

```
                   A         B
2013-02-26  1.211957  1.466739
2013-02-27  0.757892  2.925391
2013-02-28  0.271315  4.405202
2013-03-01  1.568620  0.193789
2013-03-02  3.019268  0.238964
             ...       ...
2013-05-22  0.000015  0.425237
2013-05-23  0.000017  0.651977
2013-05-24  0.000007  0.181722
2013-05-25  0.000009  0.189678
2013-05-26  0.000013  0.090490
```